# Skmaps: how unregister listeners to avoid memory leaks

Tags: android, memory-leaks, skmaps

Currently I am using the Android SDK of SKMAPS. I 've noticed that there are memory leaks when I register listeners such as surface listener of the SKMapSurfaceView and others like SKVersioningManager and so on.

Are there some way to unregister these listeners to avoid memory leaks?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Some of these memory leaks have been fixed in the latest build 3.0. In case you've tested a previous version check the latest one: http://developer.skobbler.com/support#download

Answer (score 0):

I found a memory leak with LeakCanary in the newest library.

de.example.ui.MainActivity has leaked:
01-05 11:23:07.834 4897-7713/de. example.internal D/LeakCanary: * GC ROOT com.skobbler.ngx.map.MapRenderer.b
01-05 11:23:07.834 4897-7713/de. example.internal D/LeakCanary: * references com.skobbler.ngx.map.SKMapSurfaceView.mContext
01-05 11:23:07.834 4897-7713/de. example.internal D/LeakCanary: * leaks de.example.MainActivity instance
01-05 11:23:07.834 4897-7713/de.example.internal D/LeakCanary: * Retaining: 197 KB.